# Embedded android WebView powered by react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Have an android app with WebView embedded in the main activity. Instead of loading html, is it possible to replace that WebView with a React Native component? Reason we cannot do native implementation is because of complex business logic and will be faster if we can leverage the ReactJS to create React Native implementation. Hope this question makes sense.